# Codeigniter html to database question

Tags: php, codeigniter, input-filtering

I'm working on a website witch allows users to submit blog posts, however, there seems to be a little problem. I'm using `global_xss_filtering` (`TRUE`) so everything will be filtered out.

But, when I'm using `xss_filtering` HTML tags like `<strong>` etc is being removed. If I set the `global_xss_filtering` to `FALSE` everything works great.

But how can I make this work with `global_xss_filtering` set to `TRUE` and secure at the same time? Any suggestions?

Comment: It's touching the `<strong>` tag? According to their source, it's not a "naughty" tag: https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/src/31b5c1dcf2ed/system/core/Security.php#cl-383 It appears CI has a very specific set of tags they filter out for your safety; please see the link for this list.

Comment: Question is a few years old.  `global_xss_filtering` has since been deprecated in CodeIgniter v 3.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is this:

When you have global xss_clean on, all `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE` data is cleaned by the Input class constructor via `_sanitize_globals()`.

This happens too early in CI execution for you to do anything about it later. Once the data has been `xss_cleaned`, it's impossible to un-clean it.

You have two options:

- Use a pre-system [hook](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html)
- Disable the global xss_clean

I don't have any advice on using a hook for this, but I do recommend simply disabling the global xss_clean for a few reasons:

- Obvious: It won't alter the data, and puts **you** in control, encouraging you to be mindful of when and where XSS attacks can actually occur.
- The xss_clean function is pretty heavy and aggressive, and most of the time you don't need it. Running it on *every* post, get, and cookie item eats up execution time.
- It's quite easy to add `xss_clean` as a form validation rule, or use `$this->security->xss_clean()`
- As a best practice, you should still be sanitizing your data and HTML output anyways, instead of trusting the global filter and forgetting about it.

I needed to allow `<script>` tags for a CMS for instance, and disabling the global filter was the only way to get them through. It's a big change and might make you feel nervous, but unfortunately it's the only way (unless you can figure out how to write a hook that would help).

<sub>As mentioned in the comments, it shouldn't be filtering `<strong>` tags...</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Before you apply the XSS validation you could htmlentities() and then when you fetch it from the db you could html_entity_decode().

Answer (score 0):

Short version: You can't.

Long version: Filtering HTML to remove evil things is a tricky business. It's not enough to blacklist tag types to prevent tags like `script` or `frame`, because HTML is constantly changing. Even if you did keep track of all new tag types, attackers can attach Javascript to image [onload](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/images/_IMG_onLoad.html) calls. Even if you managed to filter out all tag attributes that call Javascript without removing useful stuff like `src` or `href` or `height` (which is near impossible, because there's a billion of them), you're still not secure. You can't be sure that every browser implements every tag correctly. Further, you can't be sure that current implementations will never change. New bugs may be introduced.

Trust me, using something like [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) or [rst](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) or [BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode) is a thousand times easier to secure.